# Fast R-CNN: Running demo.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, caffe, pycaffe

I'm a beginer at caffe. i was trying to run the Fast R-CNN demo code and I was able to execute to a point where i am supposed to run the 
**./tools/demo.py** and I came across this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./tools/demo.py", line 17, in <module>
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg

File "/home/prajwaljpj/Downloads/fast-rcnn-master/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from . import train

File "/home/prajwaljpj/Downloads/fast-rcnn-master/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 10, in <module>
import caffe

File "/home/prajwaljpj/Downloads/fast-rcnn-master/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver

File "/home/prajwaljpj/Downloads/fast-rcnn-master/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \

ImportError: /home/prajwaljpj/Downloads/fast-rcnn-master/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/../../build/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8imencodeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorIhSaIhEERKSB_IiSaIiEE
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining the "undefined symbol" `_ZN2cv8imencodeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorIhSaIhEERKSB_IiSaIiEE` using [`c++filt`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt) utility reveals that the function

```
cv::imencode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  
             std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, 
             std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, 
             std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)
```

is missing.

This function is part of opencv.
Try re-installing opencv on your machine.